# SSRS CAST UNION Report Builder 3.0

Tags: sql, sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have the following at the end of a script. it is the union causing the issue

it evolves a Department Flag... that there is a

```
case when... 1 else 0
```

At the end I have ....

```
UNION
Select '0' , 'Department Flag'
```

the error I have is with Int.

How can I cast the above to Int?

using the above dataset to make a parameter

> error message = Conversion failed when converting the varchar value
>   'Department' to data type int

please help

Comment: What is the error you've got and please poste the exact query, not only a half

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Department' to data type int...thank you please help

Comment: Has worked , please see comment below, but the ordering is out of sync. the union value is in the middle..and not at the beginning. silly but any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `case when... 1 else 0`

Here the type of the column is `int`, it's defined by the value 0 which is `int`

When you do

> ```
> UNION
> Select '0' , 'Department Flag'
> ```

your `'Department Flag'` need to be converted to `int`.

To fix this issue your column should have `varchar` type, so your code should look like this:

`case when... 1 else '0' -- here 0 is not int but varchar`

Comment: brill thank you. needs case when... 1 else '0' thanks team x